# Tkinter global variable/.get()

Tags: python, tkinter, global

I'm a python beginner and I'm currently trying to make a simple python email application. I've been struggling with one part of my code as below:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("E-mail Application")
sender_emaillabel= Label(root,text="Enter Sender Email:").grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=1)
e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def entersender_click():
    global sender_email
    sender_email=e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    return

entersender= Button(root, text="Enter", padx=10, pady=5, command=entersender_click).grid(row=1, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Pycharm says that the 'Global variable 'sender_email' is undefined at the module level' and the sender_email variable does not seem to take anything inputted into e.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Your IDE is basically warning you of a potentially bad design here.  Making that variable global indicates that you expect to use it elsewhere in the program - but you can't safely do so, because the variable won't even exist if the user never clicked the button.

Comment: Why you used return here?

Comment: Ya the `return` line does nothing for you in this code as @Atlas435 is alluding to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm wants you to follow a specific way of writing code. What it is telling you is that you have not defined `sender_email` in the global namespace first. By adding this variable to the global namespace and giving it a default value PyCharm will get rid of the "warning".

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("E-mail Application")
sender_emaillabel= Label(root,text="Enter Sender Email:").grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=1)
e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

sender_email = ''  # Define it somewhere before the function.
                   # This will get rid of the lines under your code and the warning.

def entersender_click():
    global sender_email
    sender_email=e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    return

entersender= Button(root, text="Enter", padx=10, pady=5, command=entersender_click).grid(row=1, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

I personally find this warning annoying myself as I get it a lot in my classes as I do not define all of the class attributes in the `__init__` like it wants you to.

A few things to change thought.

1. Use `import tkinter as tk` instead of import *
2. There is no need to define your widget by name if you are applying the geometry manager directly to them and if you do not intend to make changes to them down the road.
3. You have no reason to use `return` in your function so you can remove that.

Updated Code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("E-mail Application")
tk.Label(root,text="Enter Sender Email:").grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=1)
e = tk.Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

sender_email = ''

def entersender_click():
    global sender_email
    sender_email=e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)

tk.Button(root, text="Enter", padx=10, pady=5, command=entersender_click).grid(row=1, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: cool! thank you v much really appreciate it! can probs tell I'm very new to this haha

Comment: No problem. We are all still learning :D. If my answer solved your issue please select the check mark next to the answer to show your issue is resolved.